# How determine the angle theta if short dipole is polarized along different vectors?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, dipole, antennas

i am trying to understand the solution: (i have attached q & solution key)

see part d,e,f how do we visualize rotation for gain function given different vector direction of polarization (i.e. in d, why does it rotate to exactly 45degree given the vector..?)

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Part (d) places the dipole along the line produced by the vector $\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\left(\hat z -\hat y\right)$ which makes a 45 degree (magnitude) angle with the z (and y axes). The coordinate system is rotated so that z-axis is now along _this_ vector. Part (e) then states that the dipole is placed along the line made by vector $\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\left(\hat z +\hat y\right)$ in this new axis. The axes is again rotated by $45^\circ$ (in the other direction) so that the dipole is now in the direction of this z-axis (back to where it was initially).

Comment: Is that what you're asking?